# Units in orbital modeling

Tags: orbital-motion, computational-physics, units

I'm trying to make a simulation of simple planetary orbits in Python (with only Earth and Jupiter) and was wondering if there are any convenient units one could use? I currently have the gravitational constant, G, times the mass of the Sun is equal 1 (`GM = 1`) and initial conditions of `x, y, xy, vy = [0.5, 0, 0, 1.63]` and it works, I just don't know why. What would 0.5 and 1.63 correspond to in SI units? I've tried a couple different things like using plank units and AU, but it hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One convenient and easy-to-understand choice of units would be to use the [solar mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_mass) ($\text{M}_\odot$) as the unit of mass, the [astronomical unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_unit) (au) as the unit of length, and the [year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year) (a) as the unit of time.

You can convert the SI value of the [gravitational constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant) into these units and discover that it has the value $G=39.48\text{ au}^3\text{M}_\odot^{-1}\text{a}^{-2}$.

Comment: What would this mean for G? And then I assume initial speeds would be in AU/year?

Comment: Yes, all speeds would be in astronomical units per year.

Comment: By the way, that numerical value 39.48 is very close to $4\pi^2$. See if you can figure out why.